# IP Address left shift representation

Tags: c, ipv4

I found the following in some old and bad documented C code:

```
#define addr (((((147 << 8) | 87) << 8) | 117) << 8) | 107
```

What is it? Well I know it's an IP address - and shifting 8 bits to the left makes some sense too. But can anyone explain this to me as a whole? What is happening there?

Thank you!

Comment: Whenever you see `<< 8`, mentally replace it with `* 256`, which is exactly what it means whenever its result is well-defined. Then see if what's going on makes sense to you.

Comment: If you understand the fact that it's shifting things by 8 bits at a time, what else is there to understand?

Comment: But why do it like this in the first place? Why shift the bytes and then do a bitwise or? The whole idea doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Well, doing it this way lets you see the individual octets in decimal, which you wouldn't get if it said e.g. `0x9357756B`, and stores it efficiently in a single integer evaluated at compile time, which it wouldn't if e.g. it were in string form `"147.87.117.107"`. It doesn't seem particularly insane to me.

Comment: Incidentally, presumably the `=` is a typo.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The code

```
(((((147 << 8) | 87) << 8) | 117) << 8) | 107
```

generates 4 bytes containing the IP 147.87.117.107.
The first step is the innermost bracket:

```
147<<8
147 = 1001 0011
1001 0011 << 8 = 1001 0011 0000 0000
```

The second byte 87 is inserted by bitwise-or operation on (147<<8). As you can see, the 8 bits on the right are all 0 (due to <<8), so the bitwise-or operation just inserts the 8 bits from 87:

```
1001 0011 0000 0000  (147<<8)
0000 0000 0101 0111  (87)
-------------------  bitwise-or
1001 0011 0101 0111  (147<<8)|87
```

The same is done with rest so you have 4 bytes at the end saved into a single 32-bit integer.

Answer (score 3):

An IPv4 address consists of four bytes, which means it can be stored in a 32-bit integer. This is taking the four parts of the IP address (147.87.117.107) and using bit-shifting and the bit-wise OR operator to "encode" the address in a single 4-byte quantity.

(Note: the address might be 107.117.87.147 - I can't remember offhand what order the bytes are stored in.)

The (hex) bytes of the resulting quantity look like:

```
aabb ccdd
```

Where aa is the hex representation of 147 (0x93), bb is 87 (0x57), cc is 117 (0x75), and dd is 107 (0x6b), so the resulting value is 9357756b.

*Update:* None of this applies to IPv6, since an IPv6 address is 128 bits instead of 32.

Comment: Only in version 4. :-P ([The term "IP" nowadays includes IPv6 as well as IPv6.](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6540))